# When a Maven goal is not part of a phase/lifecycle?

Tags: java, maven

Kind of tired of not knowing this. "report" is not a maven lifecycle. How do we tell Maven to run reporting during a certain lifecycle. If "report" is not a lifecycle or phase, then what does  `<goal>report</goal>` actually mean? When will report get run? How do we run it directly/only?

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

*Vexingly*, when I run this:

```
 mvn org.jacoco.jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

or this:

```
 mvn jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

I get this error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'org.jacoco.jacoco-maven-plugin' in
>   the current project and in the plugin groups
>   [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories [local (/home/oleg/.m2/repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

When I run this:

```
mvn clean prepare-package
```

then I get an output directly as I would hope for:

```
target/site/jacoco
```

but I don't understand why the `mvn jacoco-maven-plugin:report` commands would fail.

Answer (score 3):

For the theory:

Maven has *goals*, *phases* and *lifecycles*.

A lifecycle consists of a sequence of phases. Each phase will execute a number of attached goals. A goal is the actual code that will be executed.

When you tell Maven to execute a phase, it will run the lifecycle from the beginning up to that phase. When you tell Maven to execute a goal, it will just run that goal. Goals and phases can be easily distinguished, as goals have `:` in their name.

In your first snippet, you attached the goal `report` to the phase `prepare-package`, so it will run if you call `mvn prepare-package` or any later phase as `mvn install`.

If a plugin is already defined in the POM (or parent POM, or Maven super POM), you can call it on the command line with `mvn jacoco-maven-plugin:report`. Otherwise you need a fully qualified name in the form `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal`.

Answer (score 1):

report is a goal defined in JaCoCo Maven plug-in.

Please check this.

```
https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html
```

Usage of plugin together with maven-site-plugin without explicit selection of reports might lead to generation of redundant aggregate reports. Specify reportSets explicitly to avoid this:

```
<project>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <!-- select non-aggregate reports -->
              <report>report</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```